# How to have Spaces display desktop contents instead of desktop name only?

Tags: spaces

I'd like Spaces automatically to display the full screen contents of the desktops instead of only their names (without first having to place the mouse cursor on the "film strip"). I used to be able to do this by creating a bunch of desktops but that's no longer the case with Catalina. Is there some advanced setting that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One workaround I've found is to create 16 desktops (the max number allowed to be created explicitly) then to maximize a window.